# Why does the priority_queue pop function not delete the top element?

Tags: c++

When I delete the priority_queue element using pop, I find that it can still be accessed via the top function.My gcc version is `gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    priority_queue<int> l;
    l.push(1);
    cout << l.top() << endl; // 1
    l.pop();
    cout << l.top() << endl; // 1
}
```

why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Calling `top()` on an empty queue is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).**

Under the covers, `std::priority_queue<int>` uses `std::vector<int>` to keep the elements.  Calling `top()` on the queue has the same effect as calling `front()` on the underlying vector, and the latter is undefined when the vector (and the queue) is empty:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/front